# c# socket server - deploying, starting, stopping

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm a little confused when it comes to socket servers in terms of deploying it online.

Running locally is fine as most tutorials get you to make a server application and a client application which I can execute. Done all that for awhile now and I'm happy with it but now I want to try it using a web host.

How would I deploy the socket server to my web host and then run the server? do I just upload the program to the server and run www.mywebpage.com/mysocketserver (assuming the program is called mysocketserver.exe)

may sound like a stupid question but I'm having one of those brain dead moments.

[Edit]
Great answers guys thank you. Shame I can only mark one as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most hosting services are website related: you upload your website to their server and the host takes care of provisioning the application.

However you haven't written a website that is served by a web server, but a socket server, which is more akin to the web server itself that runs a website.

As a result you will need a host that will allow you to install and run applications, such as a [Virtual Private Server](http://dreamhost.com/servers/vps/) service, rent a [physical server](http://www.rackspace.com/managed_hosting/managed_colocation/) or use a cloud service such as [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/).

You usually Remote Desktop or SSH into the server you are renting (or own) to upload and start the application either as a normal application, a Service or a Daemon.

Once you have installed your socket server on the host server and started the application running you should be able to contact your service using the IP address for your server and the port that you are running your socket server on.

For example, if your ip address is 10.0.0.1 and you've written your socket server to listen on port 1234, you should be able to contact your service at address 10.0.0.1:1234.

Take into account firewalls allowing access to that port.

You will also then be able to use a DNS service such as [DynDns](http://dyn.com/dns/) to assign a domain name to that ip address.

Comment: thank you very much for that. I have heard of Amazon EC2 so I think thats my next place of reaserch.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer that best suits you.

Comment: My current web host do Virtual Private Servers for £19.99 ($32.11) a month. So I may take up that option.

Comment: Before you commit funds, make sure that your web host allows installation of your application on their VPS and that their infrastructure does not restrict the port(s) that you want to use.

Comment: no restrictions on applications or port numbers :-D. Cheers for the heads up Kynth

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that unless your socket server is using HTTP as a protocol.

You are using a port for your server, right? The ports are used to identify which application to talk with.

When you browse the web using "`http://something`" you really say let me get the stuff which can be found on the IP `1.2.3.4` (DNS lookup) using port `80` (which is registered for HTTP). You don't have to specify the port in the browser since all browsers know that HTTP uses port 80.

So what you are really should do is to put the socket server on your host and tell your customers/users that they can connect to your socket server at port XXX on host "`www.mywebpage.com`".

If you've built a client you'll just hard code the port in it or specify the default port automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the Internet is the routing/name translation, so that mywebpage gets translated into the correct IP address.
Either your webserver needs a fixed public IP address or you need to use a service like dynds which will dynamically map your changing IP address to the static name.

Comment: ok so for arguments sake lets say my web servers ip address was 111.222.333.444. Would it just run by going to 111.222.333.444/myscocketserver?

Comment: You have written a socket server application, not a website. It would more likely run on 111.222.333.444:1234 where 1234 is the port you have written/configured your socket server to listen on, in the same way a web server is configured to listen on port 80 for http traffic.

Comment: How would you run it on your local machine? Because of the type of application you've written you will need to rent a server that works pretty much like your local machine, whether that be Windows or Linux/Unix. You usually Remote Desktop in (or use SSH) copy the files or install it normally, then run it normally (or install it as a Service/Daemon). This sort of hosting is usually more expensive than renting some processing time to look after the scripts on a website.

Comment: You can use DynDns for the name translation and you need to configure your router/firewall accordingly if you do not want to rent a server.